# 'cbimport' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: json, import, couchbase

I am start learning couchbase. All is going fine. I am following a step by step guideline from couchbase official site. At a point, this step by step tutorial suggest me to run using command prompt. Here , I copy the exact guidelines:

```
 1.Open a Command (Terminal) window, and navigate to the Couchbase ​bin
​ folder. 

Mac OSX /Applications/Couchbase Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase-core/bin/ Windows C:\Program Files\Couchbase\Server\bin\ Linux /opt/couchbase/bin/ 

11.Add this folder to your operating system PATH statement, so that its commands may be invoked from any location. If needed, see your operating system documentation for specific details on this process. 12.In the Terminal, navigate to the ​/CB121
​ folder on your desktop, which contains the products-data.json 
​ file and ​orders-data.json
​ file. 




13.Use the ​cbimport 
​ tool to load the JSON documents in ​products-data.json
​ to the WineSearch
​ bucket (bucket names are case sensitive). To ensure uniqueness, assign an incrementing integer (​#MONO_INCR#
​ ) value to each record as part of its document key, prefixed by its ​type
​ and ​variety
​ , using "​::
​ " as a separator. 
 ❏ Cluster (-c): couchbase://127.0.0.1 ❏ Username (-u): WineSearcher ❏ Password (-p): password ❏ Bucket (-b): WineSearch ❏ Format (-f): lines ❏ Dataset (-d): file://products-data.json ❏ Threads (-t): 4 ❏ Key Pattern to Generate (-g): %type%::%variety%::#MONO_INCR# 


 cbimport json -c couchbase://127.0.0.1 -u WineSearcher -p password -b WineSearch -f lines -d file://products-data.json -t 4 -g %type%::%variety%::#MONO_INCR# 



Note, code statements in this document can be copied and pasted to your tool.
```

When I run this command `cbimport json -c couchbase://127.0.0.1 -u WineSearcher -p password -b WineSearch -f lines -d file://products-data.json -t 4 -g %type%::%variety%::#MONO_INCR#`  I am getting the following error:

```
'cbimport' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

It seems to me I may need to install any tool such as cbimport. I googled for couple of hours. There is no tool like this. I am feeling like a dumb. Any help is appreciated.

N.B: I set the environmental variable as like below:
[image]

Comment: Either `cbimport` is not in your path, or does not exist on your PC at all. can you find where `cbimport` executable is on your PC?

Comment: YES. I can it is located at C:\Program Files\Couchbase\Server\bin. I installed community version, Now I install Enterprise version again and found the cbimport executable. Thanks to pint out. trying..

Comment: ok, will post an answer.

Comment: Now getting an error: Json import failed: open products-data.json: The system cannot find the file specified. Though the error clearly explain the file path is wrong, I can't point the correct path. my file is located at:  G:\kb\Couchbase\CB121 and cbimport executable is located at: C:\Program Files\Couchbase\Server\bin.

Comment: add cbimport to the PATH in your environment like mentioned below in the answer. then run it as you did initially

Comment: Just FYI, cbimport is only included with Enterprise edition, as @AbdusSattarBhuiyan already discovered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your file is not in the path. This should sort it out (or add `.exe` after `cbimport`)

```
"C:\Program Files\Couchbase\Server\bin\cbimport" json -c couchbase://127.0.0.1 -u WineSearcher -p password -b WineSearch -f lines -d file://products-data.json -t 4 -g %type%::%variety%::#MONO_INCR#
```

**NOTE!!** now you have to make sure you set the correct path to your JSON file.

However, you would like to keep it as short as possible, therefore add `C:\Program Files\Couchbase\Server\bin` in your path variable by going to:

> Control panel -> System -> Environment Variables

Find `PATH and add

`;C:\Program Files\Couchbase\Server\bin` 
at the end of the path, then save and exit.

**Importantly** now you need to close your `cmd.exe` windows and reopen, else it will still read off the old environment.

Comment: Now getting an error: Json import failed: open products-data.json: The system cannot find the file specified. Though the error clearly explain the file path is wrong, I can't point the correct path. my file is located at: G:\kb\Couchbase\CB121 and cbimport executable is located at: C:\Program Files\Couchbase\Server\bin

Comment: yes, but you did not add the environment variable. Initially you could not find executable, which you can now. Add it to path and you can run it as you initially did.

Comment: I did. Okay. let me check again.

Comment: you should then be able to from ANY path just run `cbimport` without specifying the path.

Comment: see my modified question please.

Comment: @AbdusSattarBhuiyan ok, so do you now run it as `cbimport` from the path where your JSON file is? or still as `c:\...\bincbimport` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163398/discussion-between-abdus-sattar-bhuiyan-and-gerhard-barnard).

Comment: Do you have an idea how to do this when couchbase is running on a docker container ? @Gerhard